# Spark java Serving mp3 file (dynamic with seek)

Tags: java, html5-audio, audio-streaming, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to create a simple REST service to serve audio files (with seek support).
I'm using this example which is based on Jersey:
https://github.com/aruld/jersey-streaming/tree/jersey2

This is a quite simple example, it listens to GET and HEAD requests used by the browsers, look for the Range header and respond with 206 plus the archive slice requested (with byte ranges).
The catch here is that I'm re-writing this on spark java (a tiny framework with an embedded jetty server).

Every thing seems to be OK. The browser sends the GET and the server crates the response accordingly... though the player never loads nor plays anything. The request is made and the response header is perfect:

Request:

```
Host: localhost:4567
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept: audio/webm,audio/ogg,audio/wav,audio/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,video/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1048577
Content-Range: bytes 0-1048576/5563904
Content-Type: audio/mp3
Date: Sat, 20 Aug 2016 05:41:23 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat Aug 20 01:12:37 BRT 2016
Server: Jetty(9.3.6.v20151106)
sasd
```

One thing I noticed is that seems the transfer for this request never ends. When I close the server, the transfer ends at 0,03KB (always).

My proof of concept app code:
http://pastebin.com/xjkLne7E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer!
I did some more research and found that it is a Spark feature to be implemented:
https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/397

User tchoulihan already tried to implement such feature with success here:

https://github.com/tchoulihan/torrenttunes-client

Here is a sample of the spark get request that handles the upload:

https://github.com/tchoulihan/torrenttunes-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/torrenttunes/client/webservice/Platform.java#L555

I can't paste a blob here since GPLv3 would clash with cc-wiki license. Hes work is inspired on the same resource I first found. Based on that I have coded a version of my own that works on android, mozilla and chrome.

TL;DR The problem was that mozilla doesn't understand 206 request properly and I wasn't closing and flushing the ByteOutputStream. Also I tried to use the StreamingOutput from JAX as a response instead of sending a simple raw http response.